# Does the complex series converge or diverge?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The complex series is $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (i^k-\frac{1}{k^2})$$
I know the answer is that the series diverges.

Is this because $$\lim_{k\to\infty} (i^k-\frac{1}{k^2})$$ Does not exist since $i^k$ repeats itself infinitely? So it diverges by the kth term test for divergence?

Comment: Yes, because $|i|=1$, so the corresponding geometric series won't converge. Or the Test for Divergence, as you stated.

Comment: @Integrand Is it true that the sum of a divergence series, with a convergent series always diverges, and could i say, it is the sum of a divergent geometric series, with a convergent p-series?

Comment: Yep. If your series converged, you could split it up into two convergent series. Alas, one diverges and one converges, so yours diverges.